# Obviously punitive voting with no explanations

Tags: discussion

This is the convergence of two different issues -- excessive, patterned downvoting is the primary issue.  But that issue could be resolved if we knew what the motivation behind the downvotes was.

There is a point where a pattern of voting is obviously punishment for something.  If this goes on for a long time, there is no good reason the attribute being punished should remain unknown.

The first vote on every one of my posts since the middle of last month, except yesterday, is an unexplained downvote.

This is not reasonable behavior.  There is obviously something that these have in common.  If were just being by me, the automatic detection would be triggered.  So I assume it is some attribute.  Not identifying it over and over again is childish.

I hate to whine, and I don't care about my score, but this is passive-aggression at a level the site should not tolerate without comment.

Comment: I think this is something you can write the Team about, there's a contact link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: Do not take downvotes for personal stuff: there are mentally sick people here. If you are sure your contributions are ok then don't worry. This website has algorithms that detect serial downvoting/upvoting and suspends such users once their behavior is detected by the system, thus those votes are also cancelled by the system

Comment: @Begueradj jobermark is pointing out a case where the algorithm doesn't manage to detect it.

Comment: Right in some sense the actual pattern of downvotes must be OK, since they are still there.  But the lack of insight into their reason is a bit annoying, since it will not, in the end, result in what is being noted going away any time soon.  If I formulate a feature request, It might just be that that the detection algorithm be more stringent with uncommented downvotes than with commented ones.  Would the folks who defend uncommented downvotes find that unfair?

Comment: @Begueradj  The algorithm that detect serial downvoting/upvoting are really lenient. E.g. you can get downvoted dozens of times by the same person within a few months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Down voting with no comment](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/down-voting-with-no-comment)

Comment: I tried looking into it very briefly with the mod tools, but I'm not super familiar with how they work and couldn't find anything indicating malicious downvoting is in play... (this is probably my limitations in understanding the less-than-perfectly-clear backend that creates such a pretty and simple front end)

Comment: It's happened to me on some early posts - which irritated and annoyed me; it's good you flagged it up.